# How to use an array to keep track of different numbers?

Tags: python, arrays

I have generated random numbers from 1 to 10 but don't know how to keep track of them when a specific number comes up.

Assignment Sheet:

> Specifically, write a program (a “helper function) that simulates one
>   trial of attaining a complete set of trading cards.  How?  Generate a
>   random integer between 1 and 10 to simulate which card is in the box. 
>   Each time a number is generated, increment a counter—this is the
>   number of boxes that I must buy.  Each time I get a new card,
>   increment another counter—this is the number of different cards I
>   have.  Stop when the set is complete.  You must use an array to keep
>   track of the different cards.  This array can contain integers or
>   Boolean values.

My Current Code:

```
import random

def box():
    startbox = 0
    cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    random = random.randrange(0,10)
    while random == cards:
           startbox = startbox + 1
```

Comment: You should use a different name for the random number, for example `random_number`. If you name it `random`, you overwrite the name of the random generator module and cannot use it more than once.

Comment: Your code actually contains several errors: your function is indented wrong (def box), you need to use "in" not == to check a list, that while loop is actually infinite (random is a number between 1 and 10 and your saying while random is in a list 1 to 10), and random is overwriting the random module so needs to be renamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand the Assignment sheet, Specifically boxes needed to buy, which will always return 10, but I think this is what it is asking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random   
def box():
    startbox = 0
    allcards = 0
    cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    curcards = []
    while True:
        randomn = random.randrange(0,10)
        allcards = allcards+1
        if str(cards[randomn]) not in curcards:
            cards[randomn]
            startbox = startbox + 1
            curcards.append(str(cards[randomn]))
        if len(curcards) == 10:
            break
    return 'Boxes to buy: ' + str(startbox) + ' Cards Found: ' + '; '.join(curcards) + ' Total amount of cards: ' + str(allcards)

#print box()
box()
```

Returns:

```
Boxes to buy: 10 Cards Found: 9; 1; 2; 8; 5; 7; 10; 6; 4; 3 Total Amount Of Cards: 31
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following generously commented code for some inspiration

```
def boxes_to_buy():
    cards = [] # At the beginning we have no cards
    boxes_opened = 0 # No box is yet opened
    while len(cards) < 10: # As long as we don't have 10 cards
        boxes_opened += 1 # Open another box
        card_in_box = random.randint(1,10) # Get a random card 1-10
        if card_in_box not in cards: # Do we already own this card?
            cards.append(card_in_box) # If we do not already own it add it to our list of cards
    return boxes_opened # How many boxes were opened in the process of completing the whole set
```